# How do I re-render a Handlebars loop in Ember JS?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a template with a {{#each}} block that is rendered from an array in the controller. I also have code that removes one item in the array and sets the property in the controller to the new array. I would like for the list to re-build. My assumption was that Ember would just take care of it (considering what it does with two-way binding) but, it didn't seem to. How do I rebuild the loop in the template?

Comment: If you are setting the property on the controller, this should be rerendered by default.  Can you post your code?

Comment: Ember will take care of it if you're using the proper getters/setters/poppers/pushers etc.